# Create a script with 2 vectors in R

Tags: r

I'm using Heatmap from the package `complexheatmap`

in the script, I need to create a variable ha_column that I will incorporate into my script.

```
ha_column = HeatmapAnnotation (df = data.frame(type1=c(rep("name1",5), rep("name2",5),rep("name3",5), col = list(type1=c("name1" =  "#DCDCDC", "name2" = "#DC928B", "name2"="#BA72D3")))))
```

I have 2 vectors:

```
vectors1=c("name1","name2","name3)
vectors2=c("#DCDCDC","#DC928B","#BA72D3")
```

and the idea is to reproduce the above script with these two vectors.

I tried:

```
paste0("ha_column = HeatmapAnnotation(df = data.frame(type1 = c(rep(",vectors1,", 5),col = list(type1 = c(",vectors1,"=",vectors2,")))")
```

bu it only paste line by line such as:

```
[1] "ha_column = HeatmapAnnotation(df = data.frame(type1 = c(rep(name1, 5),col = list(type1 = c(name1=#DCDCDC)))"                   
[2] "ha_column = HeatmapAnnotation(df = data.frame(type1 = c(rep(name2, 5),col = list(type1 = c(name2=#DC928B)))"
[3] "ha_column = HeatmapAnnotation(df = data.frame(type1 = c(rep(name3, 5),col = list(type1 = c(name3=#BA72D3)))"
```

instead of doing what I want ...

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It’s not clear what the expected result is supposed to be. But regardless you are approaching the problem the wrong way. Don’t write code that creates a script. Write the script itself, to perform the necessary computation based on your two vectors (and give them proper names!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to build code as a string. Instead think of building a function to do what you want.

You could do something line

```
ha_column_fun = function(names, colors) {
    HeatmapAnnotation(
      df = data.frame(type1 = rep(names, each=5)), 
      col = list(type1=setNames(colors, names))
    )
}
```

And then you could call it with

```
ha_column = ha_column_fun(vectors1, vectors2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I just got the following error: `Warning message:
In data.frame(type1 = rep(names, each = 5), col = list(type1 = setNames(colors,  :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded`

Comment: It seems like you should have got that same warning with your original code. Are you sure the example you provided was what you were doing?

Comment: I updated my post to explain you what I've done I what I got.

Comment: @chippycentra I see. I just had a parenthesis in the wrong place. I’ve updated the answer.